# Java wordsearch method, searching given 2d array

Tags: java

I am trying to pass a word to my `findWord` method which checks a 2d array of stype String[][] "a" for said word. Row and column are the dimensions of "a". I am not checking diagonal or reverse, only forwards. I believe that nearly if not all of my logic is correct, but I think I'm getting a bounds error. No error is being thrown, but the code just isn't working properly by returning false in random cases that it should return true. Code compiles and runs fine. *(i.e it checking past the amount of columns that exist)*.

```
public boolean findWord(String word)  {
    int cL = column;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if(a[i][j].equals(word.substring(0,1))) {
                int c = 1;
                int parameter = j + word.length();
                if(parameter <= cL) {
                    for(int k = j; k < parameter; k++) {
                        if(!a[i][k].equals(word.substring(c,c+1)))
                            return false;
                        c++;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that you think you're getting a bounds error. Are you seeing a stack trace and/or exception being thrown? Please provide that output if so. Or if not, please note that in your question.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz fixed. No error is being thrown, and the code compiles/runs fine - just experiencing erratic behavior.

Comment: `row` and `column`, are they the dimensions of `a`?

Comment: What is the declared type of `a`? `char[][]`? `String[][]`? `Character[][]`? Something else?

Comment: @OleV.V. row and column are the dimensions of a, yes. And a is of type String[][]

Answer (score 1):

I have run a few test cases. I have not yet found a case where your method returns `true` despite the word being in the array.

The flaws I have seen in your code are:

You start looking in `a[0][0]`. If the string found here isn’t equal to the first letter of your word, you immediately return `false` without looking any further.

Say that the first letter of the word does match `a[0][0]`. Now you set `c` to 1, but since `i` and `k` are 0, you now compare the second letter of the word to `a[0][0]`. That is unlikely to match. It only does of the word begins with the same letter twice.

Finally, I did manage to get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, namely by searching for `aa` in a row containing `a`, `b`, `c`. Second time through the innermost loop `c` is 2, and you therefore try to take out the substring between indices 2 and 3 of a word that has length 2.

You’ve got some fixing to do. Enjoy your work.

Comment: thank you very much! I have definitely got some work to do, appreciate the feedback.